# Square brackets for \section and \chapter. What is the difference between \section{Section Name} and \section[ something here]{Section Name}?

Tags: sectioning, optional-arguments

I recently solved a problem for adding footnotes in a chapter title by changing `\chapter{Title\footnote{text}}` to `\chapter[Title]{Title\footnote{text}}`.

However, I don't understand why this works. What is the difference between the two, and what is the purpose of `[ ]` in this setting? It seems like I can write anything in `\section[ANYTHING!]{Section Title}` without changing the output.

Comment: The stuff in square brackets goes into the table of contents.  You can also use the same trick for captions of figures: If you write`\caption[one]{two}`, then "one" goes into the list of figures, while "two" will be the actual caption.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `[Short Title]` content is meant for the `ToC` and page headers only, to provide a shorter title, whereas the `\chapter{Longer Title}` is displayed on the page body. As long as you don't use `\tableofcontents` you won't notice `ANYTHING` at all (and not using page headers as well)

If the `[...]` version is omitted, ToC entry and chapter header entry are the same (by design), that's why it's used as an optional argument.

The design of of this `\cmd[Short title]{Long title}` is 'general' in the sense that it use usable for the `\part`, `\chapter`, `\section` etc, and for `\caption` (or `\captionof`).

Please note, that the `memoir` class provides a second optional argument, i.e. `\chapter[ToC title][header title]{body page title}`, i.e. the 2nd optional argument is used then for the title which should appear in the page header.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter[ANYTHING]{This is used in body}

\blindtext[10] 
\chapter[\protect\footnote{This is a footnote}]{Other chapter}

\blindtext[10] 


\end{document}
```

The example shows that `ANYTHING` used in the optional argument will be display both in `ToC` as well as in the page header, as well as the 'stupid' `\footnote` superscript.

In order to use fragile commands (such as `\footnote` etc. one has to `\protect` them or `\robustify` them (use `etoolbox` package for this, for example)

Comment: Thank you. Will refrain from using foul language in the brackets then:)

Comment: the `amsbook` document class also is a bit different from `book`: the optional argument is used only in the running head; the full text of the heading is used in the toc.  (there *is* an easy workaround for modifying the toc text if necessary.)

Answer (score 4):

The optional argument to sectional commands are dedicated for ToC-related entries. And, entries to the ToC are treated differently than that of the regular title within the document body. More specifically, ToC entries are written to the `.toc` file, which may incur expansion problems (typical of what you observed when you used `\footnote` in the section title). So yes, you can use `\section[<anything>]{<title>}` where `<title>` now contains all kinds of weird stuff, but you'll notice `<anything>` once you issue `\tableofcontents`.

Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}
\section[Second section]{Another section}
\section[This section]{This section\footnote{A section footnote}}
\section[Yet another \protect\textcolor{blue}{section}]{Yet another \textcolor{red}{section}}

\end{document}
```

[Robust commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/5764) tend to remain unexpanded when written to the `.toc`, but not all commands are defined this way. In such instanced one needs to `\protect` the command from expansion or define it to be robust.